# Virtiofsd, Problems with qemu VM launch script

Tags: permissions, qemu, virtio

I am in the process of writing a script to start my `qemu` Windows 10 VM on an Arch Linux host. My issue is that one of the commands won't run from the script, but will run in a terminal.

Here is a test script I wrote to demonstrate the issue. I will call it `Windows10Start.sh`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
/usr/lib/virtiofsd --socket-path=/var/run/qemu-vm-001.sock --shared-dir ~/Documents/SharedWin10 --cache always
```

When I run `sudo ./Windows10Start.sh` I get the following error.

```
[2023-10-07T10:42:13Z ERROR virtiofsd] Error creating sandbox: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

However, this does not happen when I run

```shell
sudo /usr/lib/virtiofsd --socket-path=/var/run/qemu-vm-001.sock --shared-dir ~/Documents/SharedWin10 --cache always
```

in the terminal. It gives the correct output shown below instead.

```
[2023-10-07T10:50:05Z INFO  virtiofsd] Waiting for vhost-user socket connection...
```

I was following [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/QEMU#Using_filesystem_passthrough_and_VirtFS) from the Arch Wiki (section 5.5). Not sure what I need to do to get the command working in my script. Help would be appreciated.